# Oracle Apex Prepare URL Link not working as intended

Tags: oracle-apex

Anyone knows why this link is not passing the values properly?
I have these two items on page 200:

P200_TYPE_TEXT (value Apple:Banana:Lemon (target is a checkbox group item, thus the colon symbol))
P200_TYPE_NAME (value fruits)

```
<a href="'|| apex_util.prepare_url(p_url =>'f?p=&APP_ID.:209:&APP_SESSION.::&DEBUG.:209:P200_TYPE_NAME,P200_TYPE_TEXT:' || :P200_TYPE_NAME || ',' || :P200_TYPE_TEXT, p_checksum_type => 'SESSION' )|| '">
```

For some reason it only passes the P200_TYPE_NAME value to page 209.
If I remove (for example) item P200_TYPE_NAME from the link it, like this:

```
<a href="'|| apex_util.prepare_url(p_url =>'f?p=&APP_ID.:209:&APP_SESSION.::&DEBUG.:209:P200_TYPE_TEXT:' || :P200_TYPE_TEXT, p_checksum_type => 'SESSION' )|| '">
```

It passes the P200_TYPE_TEXT value but on an incomplete manner (Apple:Bananas, missing Lemon).
Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide full code - not a snippet. This looks like a dynamic content region, my suggestion would be to use apex_page.get_url (which is more modern than apex_util.prepare_url) and not contatenate strings together...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why this doens't work in your case but this looks like a pl/sql dynamic content region. My advice is to create a local variable of type VARCHAR2(4000) and populated it using `apex_page.get_url` -- that is the more modern version of `apex_util.prepare_url` (lots more defaults so easier to use).

--update--

A common mistake is the assumption that this will pick up session state values - as in: the value for `P200_TYPE_TEXT` that is referenced in the url will be the value that the user entered in the form field. This is not the case. Any urls in a dynamic content region (and also link targets in buttons) are rendered when the component is rendered and the value of the link will contain the values of the item at component rendering time, not when the url is clicked. This can be verified by using `apex_page.get_url` in a dynamic content region and verifying the url in the browser dev tools.
Worarounds:

- generate the url in a dynamic action on click of the link
- do a page submit and a branch