# Oracle Apex APEX_UTIL.GET_URL Can we pass items in values?

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex get_url function, in p_values can we pass page item? or only columns can be passed?

So p_values => ':P1_ITEM'

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. It's just a function call in pl/sql so you can pass it a string or a scalar variable.
However, if you pass it a page item, then do not enclose it in quotes

```
APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (
            p_page   => 2,
            p_items  => 'P2_ITEM'
            p_values => :P1_ITEM )
```

Note that the url will contain the value of P1_ITEM at rendering time. If you change the value of P1_ITEM in the page *after* the url has been generated, that new value will not be picked up. Check the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155458/oracle-apex-prepare-url-link-not-working-as-intended) question a couple of days ago.

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question, if i use p_clear_cache it'll reset the item to null. Is there a way that i can use clear cache but it doesn't reset value? In my case, this link is used in a grid to url. So from that link page values are updated to another column. if i do not use clear cache upon update those values get copied to other columns. is there an alternative?

Comment: p_clear_cache does the same as the clear cache attribute in the link builder anywhere in apex. What value are you passing ? If - for the example I posted - you put value '2' then the session state for items on page 2 will be cleared and after that item P2_ITEM will be set to value P1_ITEM.

Comment: If that didn't help pls post another question. Comments are not ideal for discussions - and it is just between you and me, no one else gets notified